# How to find a div / panel in repeater and apply css?

Tags: asp.net, css, sql-server, vb.net, repeater

**THE GOAL**

To add a cssclass to a div that is inside a repeater if a bit column in sql table is true.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
  <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" RunAt="Server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" RunAt="Server"></asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>

Protected Sub rpt1_ItemDataBound(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
        If e.Item.DataItem("MyBitCol") = True Then
            Dim div1 = CType(rpt1.FindControl("pnl1"), Panel)
            div1.Attributes.Add("class", "MyClass")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The repeater is correctly bound on page load and populated from an sp that includes the column 'MyBitCol'

**QUESTIONS**

How to find and target a div inside a repeater from code behind?

How to retrieve mssql column value bound to repeater? 
(Column is bound to repeater but not called on aspx page. Needs to be called in code behind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find panel:

```
{
    Dim pnlSubCategories As Panel = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("pnl1"),Panel)
    pnlSubCategories.cssClass="yourclass"
}
```

Comment: That should be: `e.Item.FindControl("pnl1")` if DreamTeK was actually asking for the Panel-Control...

Comment: @sl3dg3, From his question : "To add a cssclass to a div that is inside a repeater"

Comment: Thanks for your input mark but: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl'.

Comment: Yes it will bcoz panel is server side not like div..So what is your requirement..U want to apply cssclass to that panel with id pnl1

Comment: Dim pnlSubCategories As Panel = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("pnl1"), Panel)....pnlSubCategories.cssClass="yourclass"...

Comment: Works a treat thanks Mark. As simple as DirectCast should of seen that. Can you answer why (pnlSubCategories.cssClass="yourclass") works but (pnlSubCategories.Attributes.Add("class", "MyClass")) does not? I need to add a class not change it.

Comment: For server side controls its cssClass not simply class.